# htaccess rewrite is working, but not well

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a .htaccess file, what can rewrite all URLs, but it can't open exists files. Why? I'm using Apache web server under Mac OS X with XAMPP.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /eight

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?$ index.php?kategoria=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?kategoria=$1&datum=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?kategoria=$1&datum=$2-$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?kategoria=$1&datum=$2-$3-$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?kategoria=$1&datum=$2-$3-$4&url_title=$5 [L]
```

I know that "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" and 
"RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" commands should do reach to exist files.

Thanks your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteCond's only apply to the 1 RewriteRule they immediately preceed, but you probably mean to check before all of those RewriteRules that copy the path to the query string.

You'll need to duplicate the conditions.